# Add loaded content to bottom of page

Tags: javascript

I get a page via ajax, how can I append that page to the current page?

I've looked at:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = 'Your content, markup, etc.';
target.parentNode.insertBefore( div, target );
```

But I do not want to create a wrapper element - and just want to add the loaded page on to the bottom of the content. is this possible?

Vanilla javascript only please.

Answer (score 0):

Is it it you are looking for?

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = 'test2';
var target = document.getElementById('target');
target.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',div);
```

or directly to end of body

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = 'test2';
var target = document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend',div);
```